# How to fix broken links wordpress web config rewrite index.php broke site links error 404

Tags: php, wordpress, iis, web-config, permalinks

Background:  Website was created in WordPress 3.5.1 on Windows Server 2008 r2.  Original developer is no longer in business.
Website address is http://wordpress.sunwireless.co/wordpress/
Website addressing has always been awkward, but website worked until morning of May 22, 2020 when I made changes.
Objective: was to change the address link for a web-page on our website.  Public Sector/CTF address was to be changed from 
http://wordpress.sunwireless.co/wordpress/?page_id=478,
to 
http://wordpress.sunwireless.co/wordpress/ctf

Procedure I followed:
1.  Log in to Wordpress and change the link address using Permalink field, on Pages tab, for page CTF.
2.
Clicked UPDATE but wordpress gave error message including:  ““If the root directory of your site were writable, we could do this automatically, but it isn’t so this is the url rewrite rule you should have in your web.config file. Create a new file, called web.config in the root directory of your site. Click in the field and press CTRL + a to select all. Then insert this code into the web.config file.”
Wordpress recommended I use this code for web.config:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
            <rule name="wordpress" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
                <match url="*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
            </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

3. Inserted code web.config file, with code above  in wwwroot directory on server.  Restarted server.
4. Website home page is still accessable, but all pages below home, ‘About us’, ‘CTF’, etc. respond with error 403 FORBIDDEN.
5. Searched on the error and found another web.config file recommendation, from 2015 on hostmysite, for wordpress sites hosted on Windows Server 2008:
6. Inserted this code above in web.config file, in wwwroot directory.
7. Website home page is still accessable, but all pages below home, ‘About us’, ‘CTF’, etc. respond with error 404 NOT FOUND.

Old web-site is not available.  How can I make the links work again?

Response to question asked below: "From where did you get that rule?".  The rule came from the WordPress content management system.

Comment: From where did you get that rule? The correct one should be https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/enabling-pretty-permalinks-in-wordpress#creating-a-rewrite-rule

Answer (score 0):

I found this was caused by a configuration change I made in Wordpress, but had forgotten:
I had reconfigured from *Default* to *Custom Structure* Permalink Settings.

After reverting to *Default* Permalink Settings, and emptying the browser cache, the site links operated as expected.

Sorry for any confusion.